# If Statements and logical operators in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a Money column and an Age Group column.

The Money column has NAs and the Age Group column has values that range from 1 to 5.

What I want to do is find the sum of the Money column when the AgeGroup column equals a certain value. Say 5 for this example.

I have been attempting to use an if statement but I am getting the response "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

```
if(df$AgeGroup == 5)
SumOfMoney <- sum(df$Money)
```

My problem is I don't know how to turn "if" into "when". I want to sum the Money column when those rows that have an AgeGroup value of 5, or 3, or whatever I choose.

I believe I have the condition correct, do I add a second if statement when calculating the sum?

Comment: Getting error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique () applies only to vectors

Comment: `with(df, tapply(Money, AgeGroup, sum))` should be better

Comment: @Jeff You should add a reproducible example . This will avoid help others to give you the exact solution.

Comment: What you're looking for probably isn't an if statement but rather subsetting based on a condition. For example `sum(df[df$AgeGroup == 5,"Money"], na.rm = T)`

Comment: I didn't get an error message this time. But it gave me
num [1:5(1d)] NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: Ok Ill do some research on subsetting then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `data.table` for this 'by-group' operation.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(sm=sum(Money,na.rm=TRUE)),AgeGroup]
```

This will compute the sum of money by group. Filtering the result to get some group value :

```
setDT(df)[,list(sm=sum(Money,na.rm=TRUE)),AgeGroup][AgeGroup==4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(AgeGroup) %>% 
  summarise(Money = sum(Money, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
#
#  AgeGroup Money
#1        1  1033
#2        2   793
#3        3   224
#4        4   133
#5        5   103
```

If you want to subset for a specific `AgeGroup` you could add:

`... %>% filter(AgeGroup == 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(AgeGroup = sample(1:5, 10, T), Money = sample(100:500, 10))
df[1,2] <- NA

   AgeGroup Money
1         5    NA
2         2   192
3         1   408
4         1   138
5         2   280
6         4   133
7         2   321
8         5   103
9         1   487
10        3   224

with(df, tapply(Money, AgeGroup, FUN= sum, na.rm=T))
   1    2    3    4    5 
1033  793  224  133  103
```

If you would like to just have the sum of one group at a time try:

```
sum(df[df$AgeGroup == 5,"Money"], na.rm=T)
[1] 103
```

Comment: the exact digits don't matter. the overrall structure is the same. If OP was getting a different result and the calculation was the sticking point, the digit output would have to be equal.

Comment: This is probably the answer if he wants the sum by all groups, but if he needs just for one group then `sum(df[df$AgeGroup == 5,"Money"], na.rm=T)` is enough.

Comment: You're welcome. And @agstudy I added the seed. Molx great suggestion.

Comment: Jeff, if you feel that the answer was helpful, check the v shaped arrow underneath the voting buttons to the left to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following function should do the trick.

```
> AGE <- c(1,2,3,2,5,5)
> MONEY <- c(100,200,300,400,200,100)
> dat <- data.frame(cbind(AGE,MONEY))
> dat
    AGE MONEY
 1   1   100
 2   2   200
 3   3   300
 4   2   400
 5   5   200
 6   5   100

> getSumOfGroup <- function(df, group){
 + return(sum(df[AGE == group,"MONEY"]))
 + }

> getSumOfGroup(dat, 5)
[1] 300
```